# www.subdomain redirect automatically cPanel

Tags: cpanel

On my website, I am trying to make static.domain.com but every page on the subdomain keeps redirecting to www.static.domain.com, I am using cPanel. I don't want the www. on the subdomain, what do I do?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow the below steps to create a subdomain

1. Log into your cPanel
2. Go to the Domains section and click on Subdomains.
3. Type in the name of the subdomain and select the domain to create it under. It will automatically create a folder for the subdomain in your public_html folder
4. Click the Create button. You will then see a message stating it "has been created."

IF you still facing the error could you please conact your hosting provider.

Comment: the steps you have mentioned are for creating subdomain not for the issue that he have mentioned.

Comment: If you have WHM access go to the edit DNS zone and select your domain. Please reedit the domain dns zone entry www.subdomain to .subdomain